# Understanding the bitstream generated for iCE40 I/O tiles

Tags: yosys, ice40

When I synthesize an empty circuit using Yosys and arachne-pnr, I get a few irregular bits:

```
.io_tile 6 17
IoCtrl IE_1

.io_tile 6 0
IoCtrl REN_0
IoCtrl REN_1
```

These are also part of every other file I could generate so far.  Since an unused I/O tile has both IE bits set, I read this as:

- for IE/REN block 6 17 0, the input buffer is enabled
- for IE/REN block 6 0 0, the input buffer is enabled and the pull-up resistor is disabled
- for IE/REN block 6 0 1, the input buffer is enabled and the pull-up resistor is disabled

However, according to the documentation, there is no IE/REN block 6 17 0.
What is the meaning of these bits? If the IE bit of block 6 17 0 is unset because the block doesn't exist, why aren't the bits of the other blocks which don't exist unset, too?  The other IE/REN blocks seem to correspond to I/O blocks 6 0 1 and 7 0 0.  What do these blocks do, and why are they always configured as inputs?

The [technology library](http://www.latticesemi.com/~/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/TechnicalBriefs/SBTICETechnologyLibrary201504.pdf) entry for `SB_IO` does not mention the IE bit.  How is it related to the PIN_TYPE parameter settings?

When I use an I/O pin as an input, the REN bit is set (the pull-up resistor disabled).  This suggests that the pull-up resistors are primarily intended to keep unused pins from floating, not to provide a pull-up resistor for conditionally connected inputs (e.g. buttons).  Is this assumption correct?  Would it be ok to use the internal pull-up resistors for that purpose?

The technology library says the following:

```
defparam IO_PIN_INST.PULLUP = 1'b0;
// By default, the IO will have NO pull up.
// This parameter is used only on bank 0, 1,
// and 2. Ignored when it is placed at bank 3
```

Does this mean bank 3 doesn't have pull-up resistors, or merely that they can't be re-enabled using Verilog?  What would happen if I clear that bit in the ASCII bitstream manually?  (I'd be trying this, but the iCEstick evaluation board doesn't make any pin on bank 3 accessible – a coincidence? – and I'm not sure if I want to mess with the hardware yet.)

When I use an I/O pin as an output, the IE bit isn't cleared, but the input pin function is set to PIN_INPUT.  What effect does this have, and why is it done?

Comment: For anyone arriving here looking for more info related to the pin mapping -see e.g. $PREFIX/share/icebox/chipdb-5k.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior for unused IO pins is to enable the pullup resistors and disable input enable. On iCE40 1k chips this means IE_0 and IE_1 are set and REN_0 and REN_1 are cleared in an unused IO tile. (On 8k chips IE_* is active high, i.e. all bits are cleared in an unused IO tile on an 8k chip.)

`icebox_explain` by default hides tiles that have "uninteresting" contents. (Run `icebox_explain -A` to disable this feature.)

It looks like `arachne-pnr` does not set those bits for IO pins that are not available in the current package. Thus you get some unusual bit pattern in some IO tiles that contain IE/REN bits for IO blocks not connected to any package pin.

This is what a "normal" unused IO tile looks like on the 1k architecture:

```
$ icebox_explain -mAt '1 0' example.asc
Reading file 'example.asc'..
Fabric size (without IO tiles): 12 x 16

.io_tile 1 0
  B0 ------------------
  B1 ------------------
  B2 ------------------
  B3 ------------------
  B4 ------------------
  B5 ------------------
  B6 ---+--------------
  B7 ------------------
  B8 ------------------
  B9 ---+--------------
 B10 ------------------
 B11 ------------------
 B12 ------------------
 B13 ------------------
 B14 ------------------
 B15 ------------------
IoCtrl IE_0
IoCtrl IE_1
```

> Would it be ok to use the internal pull-up resistors for that purpose?

Yes.

> The technology library entry for SB_IO does not mention the IE bit. How is it related to the PIN_TYPE parameter settings?

When `D_IN_0` or `D_IN_1` from `SB_IO` is connected to something, then this implies IE.

> When I use an I/O pin as an output, the IE bit isn't cleared

Note that IE is active low on 1k chips and active high on 8k chips. When you use an I/O pin as output-only pin on a 1k device, then the corresponding IE bit should be set, otherwise it should be cleared.

Comment: According to `chipdb-1k.txt`, I/O blocks 6 0 1 and 7 0 0 aren't unconnected; they are connected to TQ144 pins 49 (GBIN5/PIO2_01) and 50 (GBIN4/PIO2_02), respectively, which are not used on the iCEstick. — What about pull-up resistors on bank 3? Why is the input pin function set to PIN_INPUT (`IOB_<n> PINTYPE_0`) on output-only pins, and what effect does the IE bit have?

Comment: The question was about IE/REN bits not IO blocks. There is no 1:1 relationship. See .ieren in chipdb file. Also: I cannot answer "why" questions: I have not designed the chip. You have to ask Lattice.

Answer (score 0):

I found the explanation, so I'm sharing it here for future reference:

```
.io_tile 6 17
IoCtrl IE_1
```

I/O block 16 7 0 is connected to a pin in some packages but not in the TQFP package.

```
.io_tile 6 0
IoCtrl REN_0
IoCtrl REN_1
```

This corresponds to I/O blocks 6 0 1 and 7 0 0 (pins 49 and 50) into whose input paths the PLL PORTA and PORTB clocks are fed, respectively.